# What are some ways to introduce a character's name in a comics book?

Tags: creative-writing, comics

What are some ways to introduce a character's name in a comics book? In my comics, I have this issue where none of the characters' names are known until chapter 40, and it's because in Japanese culture people aren't on a first-name basis until they're very close and in the plot no one know each other and the main characters are particularly not every social, so I am wondering if there are some ways to address this without completely changing the plot.

Comment: _"none of the characters' names are known until chapter 40"_ I'm assuming you mean just the first name isn't known? Because 40 chapters without _any_ name would be quite odd.

Comment: Actually, they don't even use their last names, that's extremely problematic. They use "you" and they barely ever mention their last or first names, so I am wondering if there's a way to deal with this.